# How can one update an ETS table via mysql triggers

Tags: mysql, erlang, ets, triggers

I need to update an ETS table from changes made to a mysql table: the mysql table is accessible from within the erlang application.

I'm thinking that maybe I could have a process waiting to update the ETS table, while the mysql table gets updated from some sort of web app.

Any and all input appreciated, please let me know if I can supply any more information.

Thanks.

Comment: true, you want to keep the two synchronised, you should have a daemon on the erlang side waiting to receive those events. It should preferably be a `gen_server`, part of an OTP app, such that it is always re-started in case it goes down.

Comment: Whats the cost of out of sync (by milliseconds) data sets in your application? If the answer is not much or none at all then a simple interface over both operations within some function 'yourapp_insert()' should handle both insertions without anything exotic. On the other hand, if the system must be fully atomic then you'll need locks.. The locking mechanism will really depend on the exact nature of your system and can be quite a bit trickier. You'll probably also want some sort of 'transaction' wrapper around (exceptions!) to avoid corruptions, 'ets insert succeeds but mysql fails'. Cheers

Comment: Also, you won't be able to call an erlang process from a mysql trigger unfortunately.. (tailing the binary logs could work but still not atomic)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has no notification infrastructure, so you can't do it automatically, you have to do it with polling. You can make a table with one row which contains time of last update and then create triggers which update this table when relevant rows change. Then continuously check this table to see if it changed.

If you could switch to PostgreSQL, it has [LISTEN/NOTIFY commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-notify.html). With epgsql driver you can add pid of a process which will receive those notifications.